# Can additional share channels be added to bookdown?

Tags: r, bookdown

I am interested in adding additional sharing channels to my bookdown projects. Is it possible to add, for instance, LinkedIn. It would be nice if we could just do something like this in the yaml:

```
config:
  share:
    google: yes
    facebook: yes  
    twitter: yes
    linkedin: yes
```

Is this possible or very difficult if not currently possible?

Comment: LinkedIn is not supported: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html.html

Comment: I appreciate the fact that LinkedIn is not currently supported. It seems like it could be, though, if the following were added to plugin-sharing.js 

`'linkedin': {
    'label': 'LinkedIn',
    'icon': 'fa fa-linkedin',
    'onClick': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
                
        window.open("https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url="+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+"&title="+encodeURIComponent(document.title));
    }
},`

I'm fairly sure that this should work. I could issue a pull request if this is something others might find useful.

Comment: Yes, a pull request is welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [a pull request](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/pull/523) by the OP, LinkedIn is supported in the current development version of **bookdown** now:

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/bookdown')
```